# Jquery onclick can't target but everything else can

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclicklistener

I have two lists. I am making it so when you click the first list (instrument), you get a class list based on that instrument.
The first list is pretty clickable and everything seems to be working. But when I click the second list (li) element nothing happens. It seems so far that I can do anything with the second list except for targeting on click i have tried add class and it works but on click doesn't work.
Here's a sample.

[The left list onclick works fine but the right one doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4daeE.png)

Here is a link to the codepen

[Link to the Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxwoXN)

Here is the specific code that targets my li element with the class "classList"

```
$(".classList").on('click',function(){
    $(".classList").removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(".studentInformationView").show();
    $("#nameInput").show();
});
```

The code is too long to put a snippet here so please access the codepen.

Please let me know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are adding your `.classList` dynamically after the page load you will after to attach your click event differently, as a delegated event.

You can read about jQuery `.on()` delegated events [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.classList', function(){
        $(".classList").removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $(".studentInformationView").show();
        $("#nameInput").show();
    });
```

So attach the event to the `document` (which will always exist on page load when you are attaching the event), and it will delegate it to the `.classList` when it gets added at a later time.

Here is an updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxWJgN)